# How do we compare a end-of-line character '\n' with a string?

Tags: c++

I wanted to know how I can compare a end-of-line character '\n' with a string.
I don't really want to use the getline function because it not convenient with me.

My purpose is to increment the number of line each time I reach the end-of-line character '\n' so that each time my file read a word, it would output the line number it is at.

for example if the word "blue" is at line 2 the screen would output line 2
or if the word "common" is at line 4 the screen would output line 4

thanks,
this is my first time using the site.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "compare [a character] with a string".

Comment: Are you trying to make a program that finds a word in a file and tells what line the word is on?

Comment: Do you read from an input stream or just going through an array with something like `for(int i = 0; i < length(); i++) { array[i] = ...;` for example?

Comment: well, maybe I forgot to mention that I am reading through a file and storing inside a vector<string> variable

Comment: "*I don't really want to use the getline function because it not convenient with me*" - why not? It solves your problem of counting lines, especially since you are storing read strings anyway. So why not let it handle the line breaks for you? What is "not convenient" about it?

Comment: the problem with getline function is that it would skip the first line after storing one only word. It is "not convenient" because it would not allow me to do more than just one word... maybe there is a way that I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, the following function is what you are looking for. It will count the number of occurrences of `\n` and return back the count. You can refactor it to output the number of the lines every time it finds a new line (See the comment below)

```
int count_new_lines(string s) {
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
       if (s[i] == '\n') 
       {
          count++;
          //Output to file the number of the line
       }

    return count;
}
```

*EDIT*:
Since you need to go through a whole vector of strings, and assuming that you need to count line numbers in all of the string objects inside that vector, this is what you've got to do:

```
int count_new_lines(vector<string> stringVector) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int strings = 0; strings < stringVector.size(); strings++)
    {
       string s = stringVector[strings];
       for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
          if (s[i] == '\n') 
          {
            count++;
            //Output to file the number of the line
          }
    }
    return count;
}
```

This will return the total number of lines in all string objects within that vector of yours. For better performance and other benefits consider passing vector as a reference or a pointer, but these are a bit more advanced topics.

For future reference - this function would greatly benefit from using references and pointers instead of copying objects like in the following line:

```
string s = stringVector[strings];
```

Comment: Opps! sorry the string type was actually the vector<string>.

Comment: I have already used part of your code on mine and it didn't work. I think it is because of the vector<string> type

Comment: yeah going through vector<string> would be a slightly different story. So what each string element represents in std::vector? i.e. is each string a word, a line, a paragraph or the entire contents of the file?

Comment: I am using each string in std::vector for only a word.

Comment: Do you think your code will work for only a word as well ?

Comment: Do you want to have one word per line or more?

Comment: @Stephan It will go through every string object and if there is a `\n` in that object it will increment the counter. In other words - Yes it will work only a word as well. However I do not see the reason why you keep each word in a separate string.

Comment: Ouch - this makes a copy of the entire vector and then a copy of every string in the copy, why didn't you use references?

Comment: Thank you @kfsone as I've mentioned at the very end of the answer that this is something that the OP will have to learn at a later stage. I did not want to confuse further with pointers or references and I believe for the sake of the learning copying vector will do.

Comment: Thanks Ruslan! I will try to practice your example before using it. I might try the reference stuff later since I am still learning vectors.

Comment: @Stephan How did it go?

Comment: Hi @WorkingOtter, thanks for checking in, my real issue now is that when I use ifstream file, the variable will skip over '\n'. I guess working with file is a bit different uh

Answer (score 0):

To find the number of occurrences of a character in a string, we can use

```
    size_t count = std::count(str.begin(), str.end(), '\n');
```

e.g.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string str("hello\nworld\n");
    std::cout << std::count(str.begin(), str.end(), '\n');
}
```

http://ideone.com/mxRpKd

According to your comments in another answer you want to get the total count across a vector of strings:

```
size_t vec_char_count(const std::vector<std::string>& vec, char c) {
    size_t count = 0;
    for (const auto& str : vec) {
        count += std::count(str.begin(), str.end(), c);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/DAkWRj

Comment: I would use `for(const auto& str: vec)` as we do not want to modify strings in vector. Other than that it's what I would probably use.